# Signing binaries while deploying automatically to Azure App Service from github

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I wanted to sign my binaries while deploying to Azure App Service through github (using Kudu underneath). I understand I can run a custom script for building the project. Maybe I could use this method to sign the binaries during the build process and deploy the signed bits? I suppose I can place my certificate in Azure Key Vault. How can I access this without checking in any secrets into github?

Anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track here. A custom deployment script should do it:
http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

In Kudu you won't have Azure PowerShell installed, so you'll have to pull your certificate from Key Vault over [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903633.aspx).

**UPDATE**: Azure Functions do have the Azure RM cmdlets installed. You could write a Function App in PowerShell that pulls the cert from Key Vault. Use a [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to `Login-AzureRmAccount` unattended.

The secrets needed to accomplish that should be kept in **Application Settings**. They are exposed to you in Kudu as Environment Variables: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

> #### App settings
>
> This section contains name/value pairs that you web app will load on start up. 
>   For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET configuration AppSettings at runtime, overriding existing settings.
>   PHP, Python, Java and Node applications can access these settings as environment variables at runtime. For each app setting, two environment variables are created; one with the name specified by the app setting entry, and another with a prefix of APPSETTING_. Both contain the same value.

Alternatively, you could pull the certificate from App Service store (the "My" store). Here's how:

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/:

> Adding an app setting named **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application. You can have multiple comma-separated thumbprint values or can set this value to ***** in which case all your certificates will be loaded to your web applications personal certificate store.

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace UseCertificateInAzureWebsiteApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 // Replace below with your cert's thumbprint
                                 “E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870”,
                                 false);
      // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
      if (certCollection.Count > 0)
      {
        X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
        // Use certificate
        Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
      }
      certStore.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

No certificate validation is being done for you. You need to implement that yourself, by comparing to values stored in App Settings or Key Vault.